# Tabar Activity Indicator in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uiactivityindicatorview

I would like to add an activity indicator to a tab bar constructed inside a STORYBOARD using ARC.  I've looked at methods involving the application delegate prior to storyboards but don't seem to find anything for the current build arrangements.

Any pointers would be helpful